# ARM template deletes existing UDRs not mentioned inside of it

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I just started using ARM templates and am defining custom routes / UDRs inside RTs via ARM Template.
I also have some out of band (defined by another platform) UDRs in those RTs.
I tried defining the UDRs inside RTs as properties both inside Nested Resources and as Top Level resource but my out of band UDRs (not overlapping with the ones in the ARM template) still get deleted.
I thought that if I try this then I will hit the situation from here:
[UDRs getting overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67080491/azure-resource-manager-template-deployments-deletes-the-existing-resources)
and that then I will have a workaround.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Here is the definition as top-level resource:

```
/// TOP RESOURCE
// Define the parameters for the deployment
param vnetName string = 'myVnet'
param vnetAddressPrefix string = '192.168.0.0/24'
param subnetName string = 'vm'
param subnetPrefix string = '192.168.0.0/28'
param location string = 'westeurope'
param routeTableName string = 'myRouteTable'
param routeName string = 'myRoute'
param routeAddressPrefix string = '192.168.0.0/16'
param routeNextHopIpAddress string = '10.0.0.10'
// Create the virtual network resource
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-05-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddressPrefix
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: subnetPrefix
          // Associate the route table to the subnet
          routeTable: {
            id: routeTable.id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
// Create the route table resource
resource routeTable 'Microsoft.Network/routeTables@2022-11-01' = {
  name: routeTableName
  location: location
  properties: {
    disableBgpRoutePropagation: false
  }
}
//Add the route as a child resource outside the route table
resource route 'Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes@2023-05-01' = {
  name: routeName
  parent: routeTable
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: routeAddressPrefix
    nextHopType: 'VirtualAppliance'
    nextHopIpAddress: routeNextHopIpAddress
  }
}
```

Here is the one I tried as nested:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.23.1.45101",
      "templateHash": "547228414670873526"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myVnet"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.0.0/24"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "vm"
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.0.0/28"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "westeurope"
    },
    "routeTableName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myRouteTable"
    },
    "routeName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myRoute"
    },
    "routeAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.0.0/16"
    },
    "routeNextHopIpAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.10"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetPrefix')]",
              "routeTable": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('routeTableName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('routeTableName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
      "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('routeTableName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false,
        "routes": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('routeName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('routeAddressPrefix')]",
              "nextHopType": "VirtualAppliance",
              "nextHopIpAddress": "[parameters('routeNextHopIpAddress')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I see MS will fix this officially next year (sometime, yet unknown as the problem has been around since 2016).

defining the routes as properties hoping the existing ones in the RT won't get deleted anymore (there's no overlap)